# A riddle worth this site

Tags: riddle

So... Second riddle for me. Somehow more difficult than the last one.

> Pick a side, then relax
>   it may take a hour or two.
>   If you throw it, then it cracks,
>   but it puzzles, why would you?
>
> It is one, yet has many;
>   with it figure what to do!
>   if you possibly own any,
>   that it's old you always knew.
>
> Three Six Nine are the numbers
>   that describe me as a clue.
>   Ninety also, for the slumbers
>   which won't even read anew.

What is it?

Comment: This one seems really good. :D

Comment: @Noldor130884 - Since you don't have enough rep to see deleted answers, I should tell you that the first-posted correct answer was deleted by a moderator because it didn't have enough explanation. The discussion Len mentioned is [here](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2825/deletion-of-correct-answers/).

Comment: @randal'thor Thanks. I'm sorry to say that I haven't clue what to do at this point :/

Comment: @Noldor130884 The deleted answer has now been undeleted, so *locally* the story has a happy ending. The *global* problem hasn't really been resolved though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a..........

> Rubik's Cube

Pick a side, then relax, it may take a hour or two.

> for less experienced people, it could take an hour or two to solve

If you throw it, then it cracks, but it puzzles, why would you?

> it can break if you throw it, but why would you?

It is one, yet has many; with it figure what to do!

> it is one cube composed of 26 cubelets

if you possibly own any, that it's old you always knew.

> Rubik's cube has been available for more than 30 years

Three Six Nine are the numbers that describe me as a clue.

> The cube is 3x3x3 with six faces and nine colored squares on each face

Ninety also, for the slumbers which won't even read anew.

> Every move is a turn of a multiple of 90 degrees

Comment: I must really apply myself to create a difficult one XD

Comment: Well, you got me to sign-up an account here to answer, so: thanks for that!

Comment: I guessed the answer... but I was thrown off by and still don't get the "Ninety" part.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit this answer to explain how you reached this conclusion given the information in the question?

Answer (score 9):

> a rubik's cube? it is a square yet has many little square's, it may take an hour or two to solve

Comment: An hour or two? If you know how to solve it, it's a minute or two.

Comment: Nice try mate but that still doesn't explain half of the second and the third paragraph.

Comment: @Kevin it MAY take an hour or two ;) it may not too :P

Answer (score 2):

> Chess Set

Pick a side and then relax.
It might take an hour or two
If you throw it, then it cracks

> Chess Set can crack open, scattering pieces in the ground

but it puzzles, why would you?

> You know how to take the puzzled pieces and assemble them on the board

It is one, but has many

> Many pieces inside the chess set, after it is cracked open.

That it's old, you always knew

> Chess is a very old game

Three Six Nine are the numbers..
Ninety also, for the slumbers

> not sure about these clues..  could be reference to years in history of chess

Comment: [Three Men's Morris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Men%27s_Morris), I've still got nothing for the 90 though.